# Why are my Kivy methods not defined?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

This seems like such a basic issue, but I can't see what's wrong here. I have builder string with a widget of the form:

```
<WidgetName>:
    GridLayout:
        Label:
            text: str(get_text())
```

where the function get_text() is defined in the same file below the builder string. Something like:

```
def get_text():
    return "hello"
```

I get: NameError: name 'get_text' is not defined. What is going wrong here? I tried to define the function inside the widget class and refer to it using root.get_text, but then I get a NoneType error. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The builder can't access your py files from your .kv file. You can import your functions in .kv like this `#: import get_text mypythonfile.get_text` or you can put your function inside your app class and then use `app.get_text()`.

Comment: Thank you, this solved the issue. If you don't mind, I have two follow up questions: 1) how do you import all methods from a python file (the equivalent of `from mypythonfile import *` for .kv files, and 2) when I try to call the function to display the text of the label (as above), I get a NoneType error. Any ideas?

Comment: 1) Unfortunately, I don't think that's possible. 2) Well, something is none. Perhaps you're not calling the function correctly or it isn't returning anything. Post the code if you want more help.

Comment: Now that I have access to functions I need to use in my .kv file, I can reference them without getting a NameError. However, if I try to set the text of a label as the output of a function as shown above (`text: str(get_text())`), I get the following error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bind'`. Don't think that None is being returned - the get_text() function returns a string, for example.